# error as Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'

Tags: spring-mvc

This is my dispatcher servlet. I am getting the error as declaration of beans although I have added the `spring.beans.jar`.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

       <context:component-scan base-package="com.learning" />

       <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
          <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
          <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
       </bean>
    </beans>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is spring version you're using 3.0?

Comment: yes the version of spring is 3.0

Comment: what bean(s) are not initializing ?

Answer (score 0):

A shot in the dark but try this unversioned  declaration:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
```

Comment: probably help if we can see pertinent part of the stacktrace

Comment: not sure ehow you are getting the same error with the declaration I posted.  Mine had no reference to http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd only http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd what (exact with major and minor version number)  version of spring are you running?